# Function to Class Based View (DetailView) Django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-1.5

So my function-base view currently looks like this, and I would like to change it to Class Based View

My Function View

```
def user_detail(request, username):
    try:
       user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
       raise Http404
```

My Class Based View

```
class UserProfileDetail(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = "profiles/user_detail.html"
    #use username instead of pk
    slug_field = "username"
```

My url

```
url(r"^user/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$", UserProfileDetail.as_view(), name="user_detail"),
```

The Problem is, when I go to the http://exampe.com/user/username url, I get the Anonymous user profile. I don't want that. What changes do I have to make on my UserProfileDetail class?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `context_object_name`, because by default, `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` sets `{{ user }}` template context variable to either `request.user` or `AnonymousUser`. So, you need to override the context

override the `context_object_name` from the `DetailView` class

```
# Detail Views
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = "profiles/user_detail.html"
    #use username instead of pk
    slug_field = "username"
    #override the context user object to user_profile
    context_object_name = "user_profile"
```

and in template use

```
{{ user_profile }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added `slug_field = "username"` to your class which is incorrect in this instance. `slug_field` in your case should just be `"slug"` as that is [the named group](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) you have given the username part of your url: `.../(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/...`. Django automatically assumes that your `slug_field` is called `slug` so you can simply remove the line `slug_field = "username"` altogether or change your url to:

```
url(r"^user/(?P<username>[\w-]+)/$", UserProfileDetail.as_view(), name="user_detail"),
```

Comment: Yep, I think you got it wrong. I know that I have to do something like get_queryset and get_object in my UserProfileDetal class to have a similar function base view for user = User.objects.get(username=username)